# Eclipse Git | Reverting merge commit

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, git-revert

Using Eclipse Git (the one bundled by default on Eclipse Mars.1 - JavaEE version), is it still possible to remove/delete a wrong merge commit?

Since I'm still new to the UI of Eclipse Git coming from a terminal user, I accidentally merge the wrong branch `dev-release` to a `dev-master`. Which should have been the other way around. Luckily I haven't pushed yet that merge commit to remote.

My question is, is it possible to undo the merge commit using Eclipse Git only?

Git history

*Current situation*

```
dev-release      E - F - G 
               /           \
dev-master   A - B - C - D - H
```

*Expected result*

```
dev-release      E - F - G - H 
               /           /
dev-master   A - B - C - D
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hard reset `dev-master` to commit `D` from the [History View](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#History_View) then redo the merge on `dev-release` as you wanted.

Comment: So from `dev-master`, I'm going to hard reset down to `D`. After that, checkout to `dev-release` then merge `dev-master`? But I think `H` commit from current situation still exists on the history.

Comment: After you hard-reset dev-master to D, the H commit will remain there, but no one will point to it. dev-master's head will point to D. When you merge again a new commit will be created. From a git point of view, the H commit will look like a third nameless branch no one is using, and eventually will be garbage collected.